# CSS problem, creating tabs

Tags: css, html, tabs

I have a CSS problem that I'm not able to figure out. I'm not even sure it is possible. What I want is the following:

I have three buttons/tabs like this http://sv.tinypic.com/r/21cf85t/6 and when you click one tab a different div should show for each tab like this http://sv.tinypic.com/r/21l5y85/6 or http://sv.tinypic.com/r/2dbrv5u/6.

I know how to show/hide the divs with jQuery but the problem is that the divs will increase in height http://sv.tinypic.com/r/k2xxfb/6 and then they will push the other tabs and divs down. Is there a way to create what I am trying to do?

I'm not a guru in CSS so if you have an example to look at or can post code here I would be very very thankful!

This is the HTML I'm using for my tabs:

```
<div class="MainContent">Content</div>
<div class="TabsHolder">
    <div id="Tab1">
        <div style="width:200px">
            Content Tab 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="Button1" href="#Tab1"></a>
    <div class="clearer"></div>
    <div id="Tab2">
        <div style="width:200px">
            Content Tab 2
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="Button2" href="#Tab2"></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.MainContent {
    float: left;
}

.TabsHolder 
{
    float: left;
}

.Button1
{
    float: left;
    margin: 100px 0px 20px 0px;
    background: url(images/Button1.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    height: 79px;
    width: 27px;
}

#Tab1
{
    width: 200px;
    margin: 80px 0px 20px 0px; 
    border: solid 1px #ACCD45;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px;
}

.Button2
{
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
    background: url(images/Button2.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    height: 97px;
    width: 27px;
}

#Tab2
{
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
    border: solid 1px #ACCD45;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px;
}

div.clearer 
{
clear: both;
margin: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
padding: 0px;
line-height: 0px; 
height: 0px;
width: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/tabber/

Comment: From what I understand that works for tabs that are not vertical like in my case or can you use the tabs in the way I'm after too?

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I put together using pure CSS - Tested in Firefox, IE8 and Chrome (not sure about others). Try out a [demo here](http://pastebin.me/c5348ecc82b4b0cafb0f4a49190faacf).

Note: I wanted to make a comment about one thing in your original HTML - you can't add a background image to a link `<a>` tag.

CSS

```
.MainContent {
 float: left;
 width: 400px;
 height: 400px;
 background: #444;
}

.buttons {
 float: left;
 margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
 width: 27px;
 clear: both;
}

.Button1 {
 background: #555 url(images/Button1.png) no-repeat 0 0;
 height: 79px;
}

.Button2 {
 background: #555 url(images/Button2.png) no-repeat 0 0;
 height: 97px;
}

.Button3 {
 background: #555 url(images/Button3.png) no-repeat 0 0;
 height: 127px;
}

.tabsHolder {
 float: left;
 position: relative;
}

.tabs {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 margin: 0 0 20px 0;
 border: solid 1px #ACCD45;
 background: #444;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 20px;
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
}

#tab1 { top: 0; }
#tab2 { top: 98px; }
#tab3 { top: 215px; }

a:hover .tabs {display: block;}
```

HTML

```
<div class="MainContent">Content</div>
 <div class="tabsHolder">

  <a href="#tab1"><div class="buttons Button1">1</div>
   <div id="tab1" class="tabs">
    Content tab 1
   </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#tab2"><div class="buttons Button2">2</div>
   <div id="tab2" class="tabs">
    Content tab 2
   </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#tab3"><div class="buttons Button3">3</div>
   <div id="tab3" class="tabs">
    Content tab 3
   </div>
  </a>

 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define the pages (divs to hide/show) and tabs in two separate divs.

These will want to be floated next to each other, so you will have something like

```
<div class="pages">
<div class="page" id="tab1">....</div>
<div class="page" id="tab2">....</div>
</div>
<div class="tabs">
<div class="tab"><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></div>
<div class="tab"><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></div>
</div>
```

You can then set a min-height on pages (height for IE6, put into a conditional stylesheet), set pages and tabs to both float left, both with fixed widths.

Finally when you attach your event to $('#tab a'), make sure you iterate over all the pages hiding the non-relevant ones.

Comment: Thanks! But this will make the buttons/tabs to pop out when the page is open or am I wrong? Can you please tell me more about the min-height, what will that do for the divs?

Answer (score 0):

Without JavaScript, you cannot hide one of your divs, you can only have an HTML page per tab (like [this](http://tutorials.mezane.org/tabbed-navigation-using-css/#Introduction) or [this](http://learnola.com/2008/10/28/xhtml-tutorial-css-tabbed-menu/)).

If you want something more dynamic, you should use JavaScript. The tabs system is a built-in component of jQuery, for instance. ([Homepage](http://jquery.com/), [live demo](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/#themeGallery)).

Hope that'll help you.

Comment: Thanks! But I know how to show/hide the divs with jQuery, I use the built-in tabs for other things, but I can't see how it would work for what I'm after, having the tabs vertically? The problem is that the open div pushes the other tabs down like in this picture: http://sv.tinypic.com/r/k2xxfb/6, and I'm not sure how to solve it..

Comment: I posted an example that doesn't require any script :)