# CSS layout problem: tabs should overlap the frame

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a template like this:
[image]

The as you can see the frame (3) has a glassy border which goes behind the tabs (1,2). But I don't know how to do this layout in CSS. I searched stackoverflow and found the following threads, but they didn't help:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649360/how-to-overlap-put-a-frame-layout-from-top-border-of-an-imageview
- [CSS problem, creating tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855084/css-problem-creating-tabs)

The HTML code is something like this:

```
<div id="frame">
<nav>
<ul id="topnav">
<li>Tab1</li>
<li>Tab2</li>
<li>Tab3</li>
<li>Tab4</li>
<li>Tab5</li>
<li>Tab6</li>
<li>Tab7</li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try This

HTML :

```
<div id="frame">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Tab 01</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="active">Tab 02</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Tab 03</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Tab 04</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="frame2">Frame 02</div>
```

CSS :

```
 #frame,#frame ul
    { height:30px;
       background:#f0f0f0;
    }
    #frame ul li
    { height:30px;
      float:left;
        padding-right:2px;
    }
    #frame ul li a
    { position:relative;
      height:30px;
      display:block;
      float:left; /* for IE6 bug */
      background-color:#f00;
      left:0;
        top:0;
        padding:0 4px;
        color:#fff;
    }
    #frame ul li a:hover,#frame ul li a.active
    {  height:40px;
    }
    #frame2
    {  border:#000 1px solid;
        padding:10px;
    }
```

Please Check [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sanooj/3MMZ5/1/) for Reference

Comment: thank you. just out of curiosity what is "javascript:void(0);"? why not only "#" instead?

Comment: when using '#' there may be a jumping(scrolling effect) to the top of the page but the "javascript:void(0);" will prevent that

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the `z-index`. An element with a higher z-index will appear above another element with a lower z-index. you can use something like this:

```
.tabSelected {
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Comment: Z-index does not affect objects with position:relative. Perhaps this works in this case (I see no code above to verify...), but it should be mentioned nonetheless :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having a look at jquery-ui which provides an example on the site of a tabbed element such as this, you can modify the design using the theme roller on the site to get the colours you want.

[jquery ui tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/)

Comment: thanks for the link. I prefer to do it without JavaScript (ie. CSS)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using CSS3, you could try using RGBA for the background colour of the frame - here's a couple of links:

- [SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637921/opacity-of-background-but-not-the-text)
- [CSS Tricks article](http://css-tricks.com/2151-rgba-browser-support/)

RGBA will allow the divs to be slightly transparent while keeping the contents visible - just make sure the frame is slightly larger than the contents (so it can be seen) and set the background colour to match the glass effect.

Comment: the problem is not transparency. it is the layout: how the tab overlaps the surrounding div?

Comment: @AlexStack sorry - misunderstood

Comment: it's ok. Thanks for your interest anyway.